# What string method for matching specific strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, methods, ecmascript-6

This might be a simple duplicate question but I couldn't find any solution that resolve my case below. Please help me out! :)

---

I'm looking for a string method to check if the value matches a specific string and return that result.

- I'm using `create-react-app` and I have a `<select>` dropdown for users to filter dishes with a specific price range
- This dropdown has 3 values which are strings: "**$**", "**$$**" and "**$$$**"

I'm currently using the `.includes` method and not getting the result I want because it includes all the results that contain a character from the string. (If users choose "**$**", it will also return the results including "**$$**" and "**$$$**")

-> I only want them to return the results with exactly the value of strings above.
So what to use instead of `.includes` ?

```
// Initial states:    
const [foodList, setFoodList] = useState([])
const [foodName, setFoodName] = useState('')
const [isVegetarian, setIsVegetarian] = useState('')
const [priceRange, setPriceRange] = useState('$')

const [textSearch, setTextSearch] = useState('')
const [priceDropdown, setPriceDropdown] = useState('')
const [vegDropdown, setVegDropdown] = useState('')
```

---

```
// Search.js:
    const newSearch = props.foodList.filter((value) => {
            return (
              value.foodName.toLowerCase().includes(textSearch.toLowerCase()) &&
              // What to use instead of .includes here?
              value.priceRange.toLowerCase().includes(priceDropdown.toLocaleLowerCase()) 
              && value.isVegetarian.includes(vegDropdown.toLowerCase())
            )
          }
      )
```

Comment: What does React have to do with this? Give a *minimal* reproducible example, see [mre]. But fundamentally `"$$$"` _does_ include `"$"`.

Comment: why is it not just an exact match? what is the value in priceRange?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for the reminder, I have fixed the question!

Comment: @epascarello I tried `===` on just the `priceRange` and it didn't work. But the solution below has me trying on `isVegetarian` also and it works now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a standard `===` is going to be sufficient for your needs, since you're not checking if a value *includes* the filter selection, but that it *is exactly* the selection. (I suspect you'll want the same on the `isVegetarian` option, too.

```
const newSearch = props.foodList.filter((value) => {
  return (
    value.foodName.toLowerCase().includes(textSearch.toLowerCase()) &&
    value.priceRange.toLowerCase() === priceDropdown.toLocaleLowerCase() &&
    value.isVegetarian === vegDropdown.toLowerCase()
  )
});
```

Also, as the comments mentioned, try to keep your example as minimal as possible to reproduce the issue - it's always a balance between context and simplicity. In this case, though, showing a small data structure of `foodList` and the `newSearch` method (with a little explanation) would probably be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for your kind comment and simple solution!
I tried `===` on `priceRange` alone and wonder why it didn't work. But this works!